# How to express a set in words

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it correct to say $M$ is the set of all $x$ that are elements of $\mathbb Z$, such that $x $ is greater than $-5$ ?
$ M=${$x\in \mathbb Z :x$ is even, $x > -5$}

Comment: Is English not your native language?  "M is the set of all $x$ is an element of $\mathbb Z$" does not really make sense.  But it doesn't make sense because of English grammar. It is not an issue of mathematics.  You should say something like "the set of all $x$ *so that* $x$ is" or "the set of all $x$ *where* $x$ is".  Karl has a solution where you can remove the "is" by saying "the set of all $x$ in $\mathbb Z$".  But all this is about english grammar and not really about math.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "the set of all $x$ is an element of $\Bbb Z$" (which doesn't make grammatical sense), just say "the set of all $x$ in $\Bbb Z$". You also missed the "$x$ is even" part. I'd translate "$M=\{x\in\Bbb Z:x\text{ is even},x>-5\}$" as "$M$ is the set of all even integers greater than $-5$". So $M=\{-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,...\}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is correct, but a more concise way to express it would be
$$``M \text{ is the set of even integers strictly greater than -}5."$$